# Or with And Statement in Eloquent livewire

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel Livewire dataTables and while searching I am getting an error.

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be
> converted to string

my method for searching is

```
public static function search($QUERY)
{
    return empty($QUERY) ? static::QUERY()
        : static::WHERE(function ($QUERY) {
            $QUERY->WHERE('name', 'like', '%' . $QUERY . '%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $QUERY . '%');
        });
}
```

Livewire `render` method

```
public function render()
{
    //$this->roles = ROLE::WHERE('company_id', SESSION('company_id'))->paginate(5);
    return VIEW('livewire.users', [
        'users' => USER::search($this->search)
            ->WITH(['role', 'company'])
            ->WHERE('company_id', SESSION('company_id'))
            ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortAsc ? 'asc' : 'desc')
            ->paginate($this->perPage),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `$QUERY->WHERE('name', 'like', '%' . $QUERY . '%')` this line makes no sense, change the parameter name that is passed into your `search` method, so it is not the same as your parameter that is passed into the closure, which is an instance of the query builder.

Comment: #Remul you mean like this
public static function search($query1)
    {
        return empty($query) ? static::query()
            : static::Where(function ($query1) {
                $query1->where('name', 'like', '%' . $query1. '%')
                    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $query1. '%');
            });
    }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the actual method `search()`, you can make a *scope*, which will be rendered the same, but will also have some Laravel-magic helping you.

Replace your `search()` method on your User model with this `scopeSearch()` method. You do not change the query where its being used.

```php
/**
 * Scope a query to search for users name and email
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeSearch(Builder $query, string $search) 
{
    return $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                 ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
}
```

And import that `Builder` class, by adding the following line to the top of your User model class,

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

The trick here is the `scope` prefix, with a capital `S` in "search". See the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes) for more details.